# Positive integers satisfying $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{20}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Find all the positive integers satisfying

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{20}}$$

How to approach this question? I am not getting how to initiate the problem.

Comment: square on both side and use $(a+b)^2$ expansion on left side.

Comment: One solution is immediate considering $\sqrt{\frac{1}{20}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{80}}$, another is $(45/180)$

Comment: Hint:  show that $x$ and $y$ must each be of the form $5n^2$.

Comment: Joke answer: We can assume that $x$ is the "smaller" of $x$ and $y$. Then $x\ge 21$ and $x\le 80$. As for the other, note that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\ge 1/\sqrt{20}-1/\sqrt{21}$. Now "try everything."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $xy\neq 0$, the equation is equivalent to

$$ 2\sqrt{5}\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right)=\sqrt{xy} $$
or to:
$$ (\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{20})(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{20})=2\sqrt{5} \tag{1}$$
or, assuming $x=5a^2,y=5b^2$,
$$ (a-2)(b-2)=2. $$
Since $2$ is a prime, the only solutions are given by $(0,1),(1,0),(3,4)$ and $(4,3)$. Now you just need to prove that $x=5a^2,y=5b^2$ is necessary to fulfill $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can first try to solve $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=\frac12$ for rationals $a$ and $b$.  It is easy to show that $a$ and $b$ must be perfect squares of rational numbers.  From this, it is evident that $(x,y)=(80,80)$, $(x,y)=(45,180)$, and $(x,y)=(180,45)$ are the only solutions.